# Find the smallest and highest value of the product $xyz$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

Find the smallest and highest value of the product $xyz$ assuming that:

$x + y + z = 10$ and
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 36$.

I calculated this:

$x+y+z=10 => (x+y+z)^2=10^2$

$x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2yz+2zx=100$

$(x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2yz+2zx)-(x^2+y^2+z^2)=100-36$

$2xy+2yz+2zx=64$

$xy+yz+zx=32$

I'm stuck. What is the next step to this exercise?

My idea is to show the equation using one variable and after computing the derivative reach global extremes.

Comment: Minimum value can be obtained by A.M.- G.M. inequality.

Comment: That does not work directly. The optimum does not match the criteria. Or could you elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$x^2+y^2=36-z^2$$ and $$x+y=10-z,$$ which gives
$$(10-z)^2-2xy=36-z^2$$ or
$$xy=32-10z+z^2$$ and $$xyz=32z-10z^2+z^3.$$

Also, $$(x+y)^2\geq4xy,$$ which gives
$$3z^2-20z+28\leq0$$ or
$$2\leq z\leq\frac{14}{3}.$$
Can you end it now?

I got $\max(xyz)=\frac{896}{27}$ and $\min(xyz)=32$.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the equation: $A^3-10A^2+32A-xyz=0$, whose roots are $x,y,z$. We need to find the maximum and minimum values of:
$$xyz=A^3-10A^2+32A=f(A).$$

FOC:
$$f'(A)=3A^2-20A+32=0 \Rightarrow A_1=\frac83; \ \ A_2=4.$$
SOC:
$$\begin{align}f''(A)&=6A-20; \\
f''\left(\frac83\right)&=-4<0 \Rightarrow f\left(\frac83\right)=\frac{896}{27} \ (\text{max});\\
f''(4)&=4>0 \Rightarrow f(4)=32 \ (\text{min}).\end{align}
$$

Comment: It's necessary to calculate second derivative? It will show that curve is convex or concave.

Comment: how does this work with this reasoning? These are only local max/min values.  Cubic function has unbounded on either side.

Comment: That seems really a nice method and of course we know that max and min exist since the domain for x,y,z is compact, but there something that I'm missing in the proof that proof. I'll think about it.

Comment: Right the second order derivative shows convexity/concavity of the function at the critical point. However, the stationary points are local max/min as karakfa and gimusi noted. The solution will be complete if (considering symmetry) it is considered $2\le A\le \frac{14}{3}$ (as shown by Michael Rozenberg).

Answer (score 1):

Use the the [method of Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). The problem is 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\min & x\cdot y\cdot z \\
\mbox{such that} & x+y+z=10\\
                 & x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 36 
\end{array}
\right.
$$ 
By Lagrange multiplier theorem the critical points of $f (x, y, z)=x\cdot y\cdot z$ satisfying the constraints $g(x,y,z)= x+y+z-10=0$  and $h(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-36=0$ is solution of 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)=&0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)=&0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)=&0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)=&0\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)=&0\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Here, 
$
\mathcal{L}(x,y,z,\lambda,\mu)= f(x,y,z)-\lambda g(x,y,z)-\mu h(x,y,z)
$
In this case, 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rlcl}
y\cdot z-\lambda -2x\mu=&0 &\hspace{1cm} & (1)\\
x\cdot z-\lambda -2y\mu=&0  &\hspace{1cm} & (2)\\
x\cdot y-\lambda -2z\mu=&0   &\hspace{1cm} & (3)\\
x+y+z=&10 &\hspace{1cm} & (4)\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=&36  &\hspace{1cm} & (5)\\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, we can also try to solve the problem by a geometrical intepretation, indeed the constraints represent a circle which is the intersection between

- the plane $x+y+z=10$
- the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=36$

therefore the center of the circle is located at

$$OC=\left(\frac{10}{3},\frac{10}{3},\frac{10}{3}\right)$$

and the radius of the circle is

$$R^2=36-|OC|^2 \implies R^2=\frac83 \implies R=\frac{2\sqrt 6}{3}$$

To parametrize the circle let consider at first the circle in $x-y$ plane and centered in the origin

$$x^2+y^2=\frac83 \iff \left(\frac{2\sqrt 6}{3}\cos \alpha, \frac{2\sqrt 6}{3} \sin \alpha,0\right)$$

and since the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) around $u=\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},-\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},0\right)$ of an angle $\theta=\arccos \left(\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)$ is given by

$$M = \begin{bmatrix} 
\frac12+\frac{\sqrt 3}{6} & -\frac12 +\frac{\sqrt 3}{6} & \frac{\sqrt 3}{3} \\ 
-\frac12 +\frac{\sqrt 3}{6} & \frac12+\frac{\sqrt 3}{6} & \frac{\sqrt 3}{3} \\ 
-\frac{\sqrt 3}{3} & -\frac{\sqrt 3}{3} & \frac{\sqrt 3}{3}
\end{bmatrix}$$

the intersection circle can be parametrized as follow

- $x(\alpha)=\frac{10}{3}+\frac{2\sqrt 6}{3}\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt 3}{6}\right)\cos \alpha  +\frac{2\sqrt 6}{3}\left(-\frac12 +\frac{\sqrt 3}{6}\right)\sin \alpha 
  =\frac{\sqrt 6}{3}\left[\frac{5\sqrt 6}3+\left(1+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)\cos \alpha  +\left(-1+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)\sin \alpha\right]$
- $y(\alpha)=\frac{10}{3}+\frac{2\sqrt 6}{3}\left(-\frac12 +\frac{\sqrt 6}{6} \right)\cos \alpha +\frac{2\sqrt 6}{3}\left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt 6}{6}\right)\sin \alpha
  =\frac{\sqrt 6}{3}\left[\frac{5\sqrt 6}3+\left(-1+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)\cos \alpha  +\left(1+\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}\right)\sin \alpha\right]$
- $z(\alpha)=\frac{10}{3}-\frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}\left(\cos \alpha +\sin \alpha \right)=\frac{2\sqrt 2}{3}\left(\frac{5\sqrt 2}{2}-\cos \alpha -\sin \alpha \right)$

and finally [we obtain](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify%20(4*2%5E.5%2F9))(5*6%5E.5%2F3%2B(1%2B3%5E.5%2F3)cosx%2B(-1%2B3%5E.5%2F3)sinx)(5*6%5E.5%2F3%2B(-1%2B3%5E.5%2F3)cosx%2B(1%2B3%5E.5%2F3)sinx)(5*2%5E.5%2F2-cosx-sinx))

$$xyz(\alpha)=\frac{8}{27}\left(\sqrt 2 \cos (3\alpha )-\sqrt 2 \sin (3\alpha)+110\right) \quad \alpha \in [0,2\pi)$$

that is

> $$xyz(\alpha)=\frac{8}{27}\left[ 2 \sin \left(\frac{\pi}4-3\alpha\right)+110\right] \quad \alpha \in [0,2\pi)$$

and therefore

> $$32\le xyz \le \frac{896}{27}$$

form [the plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8%2F27+(110+%2B+2+sin(%CF%80%2F4+-+3+x))+from+o+to+2pi) of we can see that the maximum and the minimum values are reached each one in threee different points of the domain.

[image]

Comment: good method, +1. At the end the expression can be simplified to $-\frac{64}{27}t^3+\frac{16}{9}t+\frac{880}{27}$, where $t=\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{\pi}{4}\right), -1\le t\le 1$, so that it could be solved manually. Due to limited space here, see [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=optimize+t+(16%2F9+-+(64+t%5E2)%2F27)+%2B+880%2F27+subject+to+-1%3C%3Dt%3C%3D1).

Comment: @farruhota Yes thanks, I was thinking about this kind of simplification but I didn't carried out that. I add something similar to that. Thanks again!

Comment: @farruhota WA suggest a very nice simplification in the form $A \sin x +B$ which really can be solved easily.

Comment: Great. I did the simplification manually (using $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$). You better include the link for the simplification for WA.

Comment: nevermind, I see you updated the link

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a better start if you eliminate a variable (or two...)
Thus $z= 10-x-y$, so $x^2+y^2+100-2(x+y)+(x+y)^2=36$, that is, $x^2+y^2+xy-x-y+64=0$.
You are looking for the maximum of $xy(10-x-y)$.

If you do not want to look for anything creative, Lagrange multiplier surely works.